# Install node.js on PowerVPS

Tags: node.js, centos, centos5

I have one VPS from PowerVPS which has CentOS 5.5 (default configuration).
I need to install Node.JS for an [Ajax IM](http://ajaxim.com) installation.
Does anyone have any advice/information on how to install [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/) on the machine?

Comment: FYi: node-v0.1.96 is very outdated, use v0.2.5 instead.

Comment: FYI: new update. node-v0.4.2.tar.gz

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although this is not "officially supported" (meaning support will help troubleshoot problems and such), this is pretty easy to do.

Login to the server via SSH.  Then run the following commands:

---

```
cd /root
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.8/node-v0.8.8.tar.gz
gunzip node-v0.8.8.tar.gz
tar -xf node-v0.8.8.tar.gz
cd node-v0.8.8
./configure
make
make install
```

---

After those commands are run, you should be able to type `which node` to see the full path to the binary.

```
[root@host ~]# which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

To test, you can create a new file with the following contents:

```
var sys = require("sys");
sys.puts("Hello World!");
```

Save it and then run it.  I named my test file 'foo.js'.

```
[root@host ~]# node foo.js
Hello World!
```

That should do it.  If you get errors, make sure you have GCC installed.  (`yum install gcc`)

Hope that helps!

Rob Yates

Sales Engineer

PowerVPS / Virtacore Systems

Comment: Awesome, I never expected that someone from PowerVPS will reply it. Actually I am trying to install Ajax IM on the vps. I installed Node.JS and now quite confused on how to install Ajax IM. I know this is a paid support services. But if you can help me or let me know any proper guidance then it would be greatly appreciate.