# Node.js - Error trying to run server.js

Tags: ajax, node.js, vps

Trying to get AjaxIM working on my site with Node.js. I get an error however when I try to initiate server.js
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it??

The following output is produced when running this file:

```
-bash-3.2# /usr/src/node-v0.4.6/node /home/colleg60/public_html/development/ajaxim/server/server.js

node.js:134
       throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
       ^
Error: Cannot find module 'tcp'
   at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:320:11)
   at Function._load (module.js:266:25)
   at require (module.js:348:19)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/home/colleg60/public_html/development/ajaxim/server/server.js:32:11)
   at Module._compile (module.js:404:26)
   at Object..js (module.js:410:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:336:31)
   at Function._load (module.js:297:12)
   at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:423:10)
   at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing 'tcp' to 'net'

might work.

also in any case you were using the old version of AjaxIM > http://groups.google.com/group/ajaxim/browse_thread/thread/151beb1881f36209 ?

Comment: what file and where can I change tcp to net?

Comment: oh and im using AjaxIM v4.0a (the latest version on their site)

Comment: and what's your node version? `node -v` ?

Comment: I did try changing 'tcp' to 'net' but still got an error... any other suggestions? I really want to get this module working on my site!

Comment: Ok I think I am close. I finally got it to run server.js after a fresh installation with my own root login and pass. But now I get this error when I attempt to run the command 'node server.js' in my ajaxim/server directory: FATAL ERROR: v8::Debug::SetDebugMessageDispatchHandler V8 is no longer usable

Any suggestions?

Comment: it might sound annoying but somehow your node installation has failed. Can you try installing it again? V8 comes with node when you install it but now apparently V8 is corrupted. Are you working on windows?

Comment: just did a reinstall and now I am getting the 'cannot find tcp module' error again...ugh! thanks for your help so far.. any other suggestions?

Comment: Yeah I will give it another installation and see if it works. I am on a mac using terminal to connect to the root of my vps (inmotionhosting.com). My VPS Stats: Apache 2.2.17, PHP 5.2.17, Linux x86_64, Perl 5.8.8. This is the instructions I am following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227831/install-node-js-on-powervps

Comment: Did you replace 'tcp' with 'net' ? tcp module is apparently not supported anymore.

Comment: Yes. In the server.js file I replaced tcp (3 instances found) with net. When I run it (node server.js) it just hangs forever.... Seen that before?